# Homo Novus vs Novus Homo

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, syntax, word-order

To my surprise, the [English Wikipedia article about the concept of *homines novi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novus_homo) is called *Novus Homo*, not *homo novus* as I would expect.

I have been taught that Latin order is almost always substantive – adjective (*fenestra aperta*) as opposed to English or German (open window, offenes Fenster). The original Latin texts I have read and remember all talk about *homo novus*, not *novus homo*.

Since when has *novus homo* been used as a substitute for *homo novus*, or vice versa, depending which one has been coined first?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While it's true that it's "standard" for the adjective to follow the noun, Latin word order is VERY flexible, and a noun following an adjective is not at all unusual. A quick search of the corpus at http://latin.packhum.org/search reveals that both appear more or less equally.

Comment: +1: Thanks a lot for your answer. Would you mind sharing the link of your search?

Comment: I just added a link to the corpus I searched. Under "about" there are instructions on how to search in various ways.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Maybe I'm using it wrongly, but I've only found [Seneca](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/1014/1/0/11671-11681#0) and [Zeno](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/2150/1/3/12677-12687#3) using *novus homo* and [Cicero](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/73/80/570-580), [Tacitus](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/1351/3/6/139-149) and [Sallust](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/631/8/0/2793-2803) using *homo novus*. It seems to me that the latter has a higher "impact factor", or however one might call it.

Comment: @Narusan I see a Plautus reference to *novi homines* and a *novi hominis* in Terence *Hecyra* 439, several forms in Cicero, as well as *novis rebus* in Caesar and other instances where *novus* precedes the noun, all by page 6. You have to play around with the searches a little bit to see the full range. I don't know, though, when the internet decided the standard *homo novus* ought to be written *novus homo*, as you're right that the "term" is the former, even if technically the latter is grammatically correct.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I see, I am new to the database. The German books I have list homo novus as the term, which is why I was so surprised.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yeah, if you check the "About" page there are instructions on how to search. I searched for "novus homō" and "homō novus" in all the singular cases.

Comment: @Narusan The English textbooks do, too. As did Colleen McCullough's novels. I really don't know when people started using it the other way around. Very interesting.

Comment: You can also search for all combinations and cases at once using `#hom ~ #nov`, but you will have to weed out a number of false positives. It also catches things like *novi quidam homines* (Cicero) since the two words don't have to be adjacent when you use `~`. (@C.M.Weimer I corrected your typo.)